# Error when setting up GItlab Using Docker-Composer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

I am following the tutorial [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose), and came up with the following configuration file for docker-compose:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
      # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
    - '3005:3005'
    - '3010:3010'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Then I run `sudo docker-compose down; sudo docker-compose up -d` and finally when I go to `https://gitlab.example.com` on Chrome I get the error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I supposed to do something else then just running the docker command above?

P.S: I noticed 2 weird problems:

1. I cannot use `export GITLAB_HOME=/srv/gitlab` because if I replace `'/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'` with `$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'` it says that $GITLAB_HOME is empty;
2. I cannot use port 22 as intended in the tutorial because it says it is not available or already in use.

I am running these configurations on `Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem:

I changed my code to this:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.local.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://gitlab.local.com:8929'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
  ports:
    - '8929:8929'
    - '2224:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Only for personal taste.

Then I added the following line to the file located in `/etc/hosts`:
`0.0.0.0    gitlab.local.com`.